# Printing same asterisk pattern in new line n times in C

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, c;

    printf("Size");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= (n + 1); i++)
    {
        printf("*");
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int a = 1; a <= (((n + 1) * 2)-1); a++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

What I am trying to do is, after the first line with the spaces. I want to print the same line which is `(((n + 1) * 2) - 1)` n times in new lines which n is given from the `if`. For example to give a better understanding

For n = 4:

```
* * * * *
********* 1st
********* 2nd
********* 3rd
********* 4th
```

As you can see, it will do the calculation and print the line with spaces and in the next lines it will do the calculation again but it will print the line n times without spaces. I can't find out how to print them in a new line every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop is missing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, c;

    printf("Size");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i <= (n + 1); i++)
    {
        printf("*");
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");

    size_t width = (((n + 1) * 2)-1);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { /* loop for lines */
        for (int a = 1; a <= width; a++) /* loop * in lines */
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add another for loop

```
for(j= 0; j< n;++j)/*do this inner for loop and scope code n times*/
{
  for ( a = 1; a <= (((n + 1) * 2)-1); a++)
  {
    printf("*");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```